# Rock Paper Scissors PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, random, while-loop

Python rock paper scissors working nicely for me. I'm just a bit stumped on how to add up and print the number of times "human" used each weapon....

```
from random import choice

win = 0
loss = 0
tie = 0


rules = {'Rock': 'Paper', 'Scissors': 'Rock', 'Paper': 'Scissors'}
previous = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']


while True:
 human = input('Rock, Paper, Scissors or Quit???: ')
 computer = rules[choice(previous)]  

if human in ('Quit'):
    print("YoU WoN %d TiMEs!" % win)
    print("yOu lOSt %d tImEs!" % loss)
    print("YoU TIeD %d TiMEs!" % tie)
    print("SeE YoU LaTeR!!! :)")

elif human in rules:
    previous.append(human)
    print('tHe CoMPuTeR PlAyEd', computer, end='; ')

    if rules[computer] == human:  
        print('YoU WiN!')
        win += 1
    elif rules[human] == computer:  
        print('ThE CoMpUtER BeAT YOU!!!')
        loss += 1
    else:
        print("It'S A tIE!")
        tie += 1

else: print("that's not a valid choice")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with weapons as keys that are updated every time they're chosen. The dictionary would be initialized upfront before the while loop with 0 counts,

```
human_choices = {'Rock': 0, 'Paper': 0, 'Scissors': 0};
```

And then you can update the entry inside the elif after Quit option is checked:

```
elif human in rules:
        human_choices[human]+=1
        previous.append(human)
```

You can print the count in the Quit if:

```
    print(human_choices)
```

As a side note, if you want your program to really end after inputting `Quit`, you need to add a `break` statement at the end of Quit-if:

```
    print("SeE YoU LaTeR!!! :)")
    break
```

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `exit(0)` from your code if you can help it. It's mostly useful for setting an exit code should something go wrong (`exit(1)`)

Comment: @Adam Smith Thank you, I removed it. Although I can include your comment if you think it's good to do. Normally I would use break but I thought maybe there are some benefits of exiting at that spot since the while loop seem to be a logical end of the code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
from random import choice

win = 0
loss = 0
tie = 0
humanRocks = 0  
humanScissors = 0
humanPapers = 0

rules = {'Rock': 'Paper', 'Scissors': 'Rock', 'Paper': 'Scissors'}
previous = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

while True:
   human = input('Rock, Paper, Scissors or Quit???: ')
   computer = rules[choice(previous)]  
  if human in ('Quit'):
    print("YoU WoN %d TiMEs!" % win)
    print("yOu lOSt %d tImEs!" % loss)
    print("YoU TIeD %d TiMEs!" % tie)
    print("You used Rocks %d times" % humanRocks)
    print("You used Paper %d times" % humanPapers)
    print("You used Scissors %d times" % humanScissors)
    print("SeE YoU LaTeR!!! :)")
    exit(0)
elif human in rules:
    previous.append(human)
    print('tHe CoMPuTeR PlAyEd', computer, end='; ')

    if rules[computer] == human:  
       print('YoU WiN!')
       win += 1
    elif rules[human] == computer:  
       print('ThE CoMpUtER BeAT YOU!!!')
       loss += 1
    else:
       print("It'S A tIE!")
       tie += 1
    if human == "Rock":
       humanRocks+=1
    elif human == "Paper":
       humanPapers+=1
    elif human == "Scissors":
       humanScissors+=1 

    else: print("that's not a valid choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

c1=[0];p1=[0];t=1
result={-1:p1,-2:c1,1:c1,2:p1,0:[0]}
opt=["exit","Rock","Paper","Scissors",]

while 1:
    print("\n","-"*30,sep="")   
    comp= random.randint(1,3)   
    user=input("Choose Option\n1. %s 2. %s 3. %s 0. %s\n>>"%(opt[1],opt[2],opt[3],opt[0]))
    if user not in ['1','2','3']:break
    user=int(user)
    print("Comp--> %s -- %s <--You"%(opt[comp],opt[user]))    
    g=result[comp-user]
    g[0]+=1
    print("\n---Score---\nComp--> %s\nYou--> %s\n----------"%(c1[0],p1[0]))    
print("\n------------------\n %s won!\n------------------"%("Computer" if c1[0]>p1[0] else "You"))
```

Comment: Giving answer is good, but if you explain it, it would be better